# OSX - How can I copy a local users settings/preferences to a new mobile user

Tags: mac-osx, bash, terminal

We are working on migrating all our local users to mobile accounts that are bound to LDAP. I am working on a script that prompts a user to enter their email and it creates a new mobile user and then moves all their files and also their preferences.

Perfect world, user logs out of local account and into the new account and it looks just like it did before the move (including desktop wallpaper,dock settings, etc..).

I've figured out how to create the mobile account from user prompt.

I think I have the files figured out using mv due to the amount of files/folders are too big to copy.

What I am having issues is with the settings/preferences.

I've figured that the keychain isn't going to work easily so I'm ok with that not being a part of it.

I've tried rsync'ing the Library/Preferences but it's not working....
Anyone had any experience with this?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

When you speak of a "mobile user", do you mean one defined in LDAP but with a local (to the client) home folder? If so, I've done this (with Active Directory rather than LDAP, and an older version of OS X) simply by renaming the home folder (from /Users/localacctname to /Users/LDAPacctname) and doing a `chown -R LDAPacctUID /Users/LDAPacctname`. There were a few issues, but nothing too serious:

- As you said, the keychain doesn't work cleanly. But the only problem we saw was that the account password no longer worked to unlock it at login; this means the first time the user logs into their new account they receive a warning that "[The system was unable to unlock your login keychain...](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3799)" They should be able to click "Update Keychain Password", enter their old (local account) password, and resynchronize everything.

  Note that OS X 10.9 introduced a new keychain ("Local Items") in a different format, and it's possible this will complicate matters. I have not tested this.
- Some programs had stored file locations (e.g. in their preferences), and got confused when everything was at different paths. IIRC VMWare virtual machines were the most common example of this. Fixing this simply required telling the program where everything had moved to.